# Recognizing individual voices

Tags: signal-processing, speech

I plan to write a conversation analysis software, which will recognize the individual speakers, their pitch and intensity. Pitch and intensity are somewhat straightforward (pitch via autocorrelation).

How would I go about recognizing individual speakers, so I can record his/her features? Will storing some heuristics for each speaker's frequencies be enough? I can assume that only one person speaks at a time (strictly non-overlapping). I can also assume that for training, each speaker can record a minute's worth of data before actual analysis.

Comment: How are you going to handle intensity?  Is the microphone always a fixed distance from the person speaking?

Comment: I am sure there are doctoral theses on this subject, I am not sure if their authors are active on stackoverflow however...

Comment: This is what interns or post-docs are for, as their aural pattern recognizers have been being debugged for millions of years.

Answer (score 2):

Pitch and intensity on their own tell you nothing. You really need to analyse how pitch *varies*. In order to identify different speakers you need to transform the speech audio into some kind of *`feature space`*, and then make comparisons against your database of speakers in this feature space. The general term that you might want to Google for is *`prosody`* - see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosody_(linguistics). While you're Googling you might also want to read up on *`speaker identification`* aka *`speaker recognition`*, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_identification

Answer (score 0):

If you are still working on this...  are you using speech-recognition on the sound input? Because Microsoft SAPI for example provides the application with a rich API for digging into the speech sound wave, which could make the speaker-recognition problem more tractable. I think you can get phoneme positions within the waveform. That would let you do power-spectrum analysis of vowels, for example, which could be used to generate features to distinguish speakers. (Before anybody starts muttering about pitch and volume, keep in mind that the formant curves come from vocal-tract shape and are fairly independent of pitch, which is vocal-cord frequency, and the relative position and relative amplitude of formants are (relatively!) independent of overall volume.) Phoneme duration in-context might also be a useful feature. Energy distribution during 'n' sounds could provide a 'nasality' feature. And so on.  Just a thought.  I expect to be working in this area myself.